# Azure Functions: IDurableOrchestrationContext.CurrentUtcDateTime vs DateTime.UtcNow

Tags: azure-functions

**My question in general:** how to get a current date and time in azure orchestrator function in a proper way?

Azure team recommends using deterministic code that returns the same value on every orchestration replay.
I understand that and had used IDurableOrchestrationContext.CurrentUtcDateTime as recommended until I realized that it doesn't work in my case.

**My case in general:** my an orchestrator sends some data to the 3rd party system. This system might send a response that it is busy and the caller needs to wait for X minutes. Orchestrator then is paused using standard context.CreateTimer() method. CreateTimer() uses DateTime object as a first parameter to instruct Durable Framework when the orchestrator needs to be awakened (replayed) *and to calculate this first parameter I need the current date and time*. As soon as orchestrator is replayed it tries to send data one more time and it might fail again and wait for X minutes again. In other words there is a while(MaxAttemptsNumber) { ...try to send data somewhere... }

Here is an example when the process fails:

*Orchestrator 1st run (not replayed) – Current time is 12:00*

Data is send and the 3rd party system tells to wait for 30 minutes.
I get the current time using IDurableOrchestrationContext.CurrentUtcDateTime and add 30 minutes then pass it to context.CreateTimer(). Thread sleeps until 12:30

*Orchestrator 2st run (replayed) – Current time is 12:30*

Durable Framework unloaded my orchestrator from memory and it needs to be replayed. It loads my orchestrator again, initializes all the values with old/previous values until it gets to context.CreateTimer() line of code again ends a previous attempt and tries to send same data one more time. Gets a failure again and an instruction from 3rd party system to wait for 1 minute. No problem!
I get the current time using IDurableOrchestrationContext.CurrentUtcDateTime and add 1 minutes then pass it to context.CreateTimer().
However I see that on replay the value in IDurableOrchestrationContext.CurrentUtcDateTime is the same as it was in the first run: 12:00 (and a real current time is 12:30...)
So, in this case the first parameter for context.CreateTimer() will be 12:01 and this thread will never be awakened... (again since the current time is 12:30) - Tested it already. It just hangs forever.

In addition to the main question above couple of more:

1. ... main question is at the top of this post ...
2. why wouldn't context.CreateTimer() use TimeSpan object instead of DateTime? :)
3. Is there a real example of usage when storing old current time on replay using IDurableOrchestrationContext.CurrentUtcDateTime?
4. Is it safe in my case to use DateTime.UtcNow/DateTime.Now?

Thank you!

**UPD:**
Screenshot while debugging:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me the following orchestrator works as expected:

```cs
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task RunOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(log);
        int attempt = 0;
        while (attempt < 5)
        {
            var result = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Activity", attempt);
            if (result == "OK")
            {
                break;
            }

            var fireAt = context.CurrentUtcDateTime + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            log.LogInformation("Retrying at {RetryTime}", fireAt);
            await context.CreateTimer(fireAt, default);
            attempt++;
        }
    }

    [FunctionName("Function1_Activity")]
    public static async Task<string> TestActivity([ActivityTrigger] int attempt)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        if (attempt >= 3)
        {
            return "OK";
        }

        return "FAIL";
    }

    [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // Function input comes from the request content.
        string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", null);

        log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

        return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
    }
}
```

I get log messages like this:

> Retrying at 03/12/2021 18:10:17
>
> Retrying at 03/12/2021 18:11:43
>
> Retrying at 03/12/2021 18:13:11

The `CurrentUtcDateTime` property's value updates as the replay progresses.
On the first replay round through the code value will be same yes.
But the Durable Task framework will see the timer has already expired and continues the loop to next iteration.
Then there the current time will have changed already to a new value.

I also made the logger "replay-safe" so that we don't get log messages from the loop iterations that get replayed.

And no, it is not safe to use DateTime.UtcNow in this case.
The code needs to call CreateTimer again on replay with the same parameters as before.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think while debugging I saw incorrect values and thought that this is an issue, but not I think this is by design when replaying the function. I've added a screenshot to the original post when debugging...

Comment: In your case it looks more like the variable still has the same value since it was assigned before the CreateTimer call. After that await on replay, the variable currentContextDt won't have changed (until the next loop iteration), but the context.CurrentUtcDateTime property will actually have a new value.